# How to run beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler after stoping location updates?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios8, background

I'm looking for a way to run `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` even  location updates has been stoped. Is that possible? or i need to update anything?

Note : i have noticed that beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler is calling until getting location updates.

Answer (score 0):

Once you're in the background you can only have 10 minutes of additional time. There is no way to extend that.

You should use the location background services instead.